# what is the address of a font in assets folder - android studio

Tags: android, webview, fonts, assets

I have a webView in my app and I need to set the font-family from a .ttf font which is inside the assets folder, here is my String which fills the webView :

```
String font_size = 24;
String font_family;
String main_txt = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body dir='rtl' style='font-size: " +font_size+"px; 'font-family: "+font_family+";"+">" + "<text-align: justify;' >" + book.get("content").toString() + "</body>" + "</html>";
```

My question is how I can refer to that .ttf font in my font_family variable in order to change the WebView font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the address of a file in app:\src\main\assest is "file:///android_asset/a.ttf" in android studio

Answer (score 2):

If you reference your fonts as `fonts/mytypeface.ttf`, it would work with any `assets/fonts/*` file.

```
// Font must be placed in assets/fonts folder
@font-face {
  font-family: spqr; src: url('fonts/spqr.ttf');
}
```

Comment: so my just my font_family must be :
String font_family = "spqr; src: url('fonts/spqr.ttf')";
if I have spqr.ttf in my assets/fonts
but that didn't work

Comment: It really should ^^ Just to make sure, please specify the path like so `src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/spqr.ttf')` in the HTML if you can (it might be a relative path problem).